# facebook api - Page object missing several properties

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When querying facebook graph's api I see that there are several properties missing, for example these properties:

- General information
- Mission

Is this on purpose? Is it possible to somehow retrieve these properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mission` and `general_info` still exist.  Use FQL to get it. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/  To do FQL via the graph is simple:  `http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q={your fql}&access_token={accessToken}`.  Play with it here:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer